# PDF of the Absolute Value of the Sum of Two Random Variables Each Chosen From An Asymmetric PDF

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions

**Original Question:**

If two random variables ($μ_1$  & $μ_2$) are chosen from the following probability distribution (PDF) $$P_{\mu} (\mu)= \frac{1}{2\pi^2 \sqrt{1-\mu^2 }} \left(\pi-2\mu\sqrt{1-\mu^2 }+2\cos^{-1} \mu\right);\mu\in(-1,+1)$$

What will be the PDF $P_M (M)$ of the absolute value of their sum 
$\left(M=|\mu_1+\mu_2|\right)$ ?

**Details of Where I am Stuck:**

It can be shown that the $P_M(M)$ can be expressed as: (Pardon for the image instead of LaTeX equation. Stackexchange was showing math processing error which I could not resolve)
[image: PieceWise Description]

The above piecewise expression is written by keeping the following two figures (respectively for $M \in[0,1]$ and $M \in[1,2]$) in mind:
[image: Favorable region in mu1 mu2 space for M in 0 to 1]
[image: Favorable region in mu1 mu2 space for M in 1 to 2]

However, I am unable to simplify the convoluted integral using any standard or advanced integration techniques I am aware of.

**Why This Is Interesting:**

Being aware of the real physical context of the problem, I know that its solution in analytical form exists. So I am not looking for numerical methods to solve the convoluted integral, but to solve it analytically. I feel I am limited by my ability to integrate here despite having a relevant background and significant amount of experience in solving such problems.

Comment: In principle you can convolve and then use the definition of absolute value. Did you try this already?

Comment: Yes. I got stuck at the integral. I could not solve it using any basic or advanced integration techniques I know. May be I will edit my post and also show that convoluted integral where I am stuck.

Comment: you should add this context your question. You may have to use numerical methods instead.

Comment: I have updated my post. But at the same time, being aware of the real physical context of the problem, I know that its solution in analytical form exists. So I am not looking for numerical methods.

Comment: I had some time to look at this again and I would like some more clarification. Define $F(x)=\frac{\pi-2x\sqrt{1-x^2}+2\arccos{x}}{2\pi^2 \sqrt{1-x^2}}$ as what you say is your distribution, so the CDF of some RV $X$ (right? or did you mean this to be the probability density function?). If so... we can inspect a minimum occurs at $x\approx 0.552569220342083$, while it blows up to $\infty$ at $\pm 1$, so $F$ is not monotonic and $\lim_{x\to 1} F(x)\neq 1$ and $\lim_{x\to-1} F(x)\neq 0$ (they're both infinite!), so $F$ does not satisfy three properties of CDFs ...(continued)

Comment: (continued) even further, if we still expected $F$ could be a CDF, we could try to find its associated density (if it exists) to see that $f(x):=F'(x)=\frac{2\sqrt{1-x^2} (x^2-2)+\pi x+2x\arccos{x}}{2\pi^2 (1-x^2)^{3/2}}$ does not integrate to unity over your given range $(-1,1)$, i.e. $\int_{-1}^1 f(x) dx$ diverges. So I don't think $F$ is a CDF, for these reasons, and this problem could use more context and clarification, unless I'm severely mistaken, in which case you should not hesitate to correct me.

Comment: And finally, $\int_{-1}^1 F(x) dx = 1$, and $F(x)>0$ so $F$ can play the role of the probability density function of some RV $X$, such that $G(x)=\int_{-1}^x F(u)du=\frac{\pi \arcsin{x}-\arccos{x}^2-x^2}{2\pi^2}+3/4+1/(2\pi^2)$ is a valid CDF with $\lim_{x\to 1} G(x)=1$, $\lim_{x\to -1} G(x)=0$ and $G$ is monotonically increasing (and so $0\leq G(x)\leq 1$, representing probabilities). So, you should clarify what you meant by the given function $F$, is it supposed to be a CDF or PDF?

Comment: It is a PDF, not CDF.

Comment: I have updated the title. We in our institute use PDF and Probability Distribution interchangeably.

Comment: Indeed, many (of my favorite) authors do so too, but it is not always clear from context without having to check properties. I will see if I can get anywhere with the convolution now.

Answer (score 1):

This is an extended comment rather than an answer.

I don't know why you believe an analytical form exists.  For whatever it's worth, I have not found an analytic form using *Mathematica*.  Maybe *MATLAB* or *Maple* would have better luck.

Using numerical methods as a check on whatever analytical form you might find is recommended.  Here's how that would be done in *Mathematica*:

```
p[μ_] := (π - μ Sqrt[1 - μ^2] - ArcSin[μ])/(π^2 Sqrt[1 - μ^2])
pdf = Table[{m, NIntegrate[p[μ] p[m - μ] + p[-μ] p[μ - m], {μ, m - 1, 1}]},
   {m, 0 + 1/100, 2 - 1/100, 1/100}];
ListPlot[pdf, PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, 1.1}}, Joined -> True, Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, Bold, 18] &) /@ {"M", "PDF"}]
```

[image: PDF of M]